# PHP Cors/Rewriting pictures in folder to other domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder structure like:

```
- app.domain.com
  / files of page
  / images (my images i want to load)
    / upload (subfolder)
      / picture.png (Here it is my picture)
```

Now I want to load on my second domain:

domain.com

the pictures with the same structure without having to copy them like this

```
domain.com/images/upload/picture.png
```

Could smb explain me how to do this with cores or with some .htaccess rewriting?

-> Info: both domains are on the same server with plesk ...

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe use a reverse proxy, https://serverfault.com/questions/619479/apache-proxy-based-on-url-suffixes also something like an origin pull cdn would work.

Comment: thank you, but i wish it would be easier because it should be just an easy thing with a .htaccess without an extra server or cdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by searching for .htaccess rewrite options ...

I'm now pointing my folder to the other domain like this:

RewriteRule ^users/(.+)?/?$ https://app.domain.com/upload/users/$1 [NC,L]

Best Regards